# Get unused id from a field with "AUTO_INCREMENT" - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

Suppose I have a field in a table say `tb_example` named `id`. This `id` is with **AUTO_INCREMENT** property. So in every new insert it goes like 1,2,3,..... and so on.

Now suppose there are 10 rows of data with id 1-10. Somebody deleted the data where `id=5`. Now for the next insert I want to insert data in **position 5 NOT IN 11** Also I want to get the **unused** `id` before insertion. That means I want to get the unused `id` and insert the next data using query like

```
"INSERT INTO tb_example .......... WHERE id=".$unused_id;
```

**Is it possible with any simple function or process to get that unused `id`?** Also is it possible to get unused `id` inside a range? Like I want to know if any unused `id` exists inside 100 to 200? Or do I need to find that `id` with logical coding? Please help....

Comment: Side note: I'd be surprised if MySQL allows that - you probably will need regular column with some complicated logic of assigning IDs (and making sure that you properly handle multiple requests for "give/reserve me lowest unused id")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient way of getting the next unused id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568912/most-efficient-way-of-getting-the-next-unused-id)

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @RafeKettler I need it in an existing accounting software to handle their referencing system.

Comment: This will be **slow**, and it will only catch missing IDs immediately preceded by existing IDs, but you can try this approach: `SELECT q.id + 1 FROM tb_example q WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT w.id FROM tb_example w WHERE w.id = q.id + 1) ORDER BY q.id ASC LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the lowest friction approach is probably to have a separate table recording reusable IDs that you insert into each time a record is deleted (ideally with a trigger). when you want to insert a new record, look aside at this table and see if there are IDs to reuse. if so, use them; if not, just insert normally. this should also allow you to easily find an unused ID in a range. this should be fast provided the column in the look-aside table storing each recyclable ID is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary. Firstly if it was to do that it would have to search the index (tree?) for any unused numbers. Imagine if you had a million rows then that would be quite slow, for even a simple insert. The id can also be used as a rudimentary order of insert, if you start reusing then this is ruined.

Comment: It's unreasonable to say that scanning the whole table is the only way. You could store deleted IDs in a separate table. But you're right that there is probably no use case for this.

Comment: Why I would ask if I don't need this?? I just don't get it why people in stackoverflow thinks more about the use case rather than the solution. Anyway I need it in an existing accounting software. And no they have only 5000 rows max with different account using different range of id.

Comment: I would just keep a separate table for ids that are free, maybe try a sql trigger for on delete add to id table. Not sure how to set that up though. @Rafe you're right, I hadn't put much thought into it